# JavaScript: Not getting location via Geolocation API

Tags: javascript, html, geolocation

I am doing an exercise out of a book and for some reason I can't get the Geolocation API to send me back my coordinates. The browser prompts me for permission to obtain my location, so that much is working, but it does not update the text in the `div` with the "location" id.

I think I am accessing the element correctly through the `document.getElementById` function.

HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset = "utf-8">
        <title>Where am I?</title>
        <script src="loc.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="loc.css">
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="location">
            Your location will be here.
        </div>
    </body>

</html>
```

JS:

```
window.onload = getMyLocation; 

function getMyLocation(){
    if(navigator.geolocation){
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(displayLocation); 
    } else {
        alert("Ooops, no geolocation support!")
    }
}

function displayLocation(position){
    var latitude = position.coords.latitude; 
    var longitude = position.coords.longitude; 

    var div = document.getElementById("location");
    div.innerHTML = "You are at Latitude: " + latitude + ", Longtitude: " + longitude;
}
```

Comment: I just ran your code and it worked.   Are you getting lat/lon from Google correctly and only display is not working?

Comment: I just get prompted to give permission (which I do), but the page does not update from the original HTML. It just says "Your location will be here." If you're getting "You are at Latitude: X, Longitude: Y" then I guess the problem is at my end and not the code.

Comment: In your code after var longitude put in alert(longitude);  You should get a number.

Answer (score 0):

You must use httpS on most browsers these days to access geolocation. Localhost URLs may or maynot work.